# Making an in-line statement without a table or a cte

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to do the following without using a #Temp table or a table variable. Can't do CTE with a GROUP BY. Is there a way to do this?

```
select Title, count(*) as PlayCount
into #Temp
from LC l 
join Play p on p.lcID = l.lcID
group by Title

declare @Max int 
select @Max = max(PlayCount) from #Temp

select Title, PlayCount, cast(PlayCount as float) / cast(@Max as float) as Weight
from #Temp
```

Comment: Why can't you use a CTE?

Comment: group by not allowed in a cte

Comment: @Metaphor - Yes it is!

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  I think this was a limitation when CTEs were first introduced.

Comment: @db_brad - No there has never been any such limitation that you can't use `GROUP BY` in CTEs.

Comment: from SQL Server 2012 docs...  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

Comment: damn, that was limitations for a RECURSIVE cte. I mis-read it. duh!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a subquery/cte and `MAX() OVER()`:

```
SELECT Title, PlayCount, PlayCount*1.0 / Max_CT AS WEIGHT
FROM (SELECT Title
           , COUNT(*) AS PlayCount
           , MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER() AS Max_CT
      FROM LC l 
      JOIN PLAY P ON P.LCID = L.LCID
      GROUP BY Title
     )sub
```

(Assuming MS SQL 2005 or newer)

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

sub query? perhaps not the cleanest

```
select Title, count(*) as PlayCount , count(*) / tot
from LC l join Play p on p.lcID = l.lcID ,
(select max(a) as tot from (select count(*)  as a from LC group by lcid))
group by Title , tot
```

not entirely sure which table is doing what, but above should give you an idea

Comment: Yes, got the idea, thanks. I considered this and might end up using it. The Play table is in the hundreds of millions of records, though. Hoping for a more efficient idea.

Comment: why not create a warehouse of some description then?

Answer (score 0):

```
select Title, count(*) as PlayCount, cast(count(*) as float) / cast(
(
select max(PlayCount) from (select count(*) as PlayCount
from LC l 
join Play p on p.lcID = l.lcID
group by Title
) q) as float) as Weight
from LC l
join Play p on p.lcID = l.lcID
group by title
```

I think this is at least close. But the "no CTE" requirement seem artificial - is this a lab test at university or s.t.?

Comment: No, just mis-read the cte documentation. group by not allowed in recursive cte. When I got this job, no one told me I need to know how to read.